# How to get list of bitorrent tracker urls

Tags: bittorrent, libtorrent

I have come across a list of bitorrent trackers in a text file about 100 of them.My question is how are they able to generate this text file with so many trackers like that.anybody with a script that generates this tracker urls?
example of a bittorent tracker is : http://3dfreedom.ru:6969/announce

Comment: Oh my nobody has an idea or even a clue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no central directory of trackers, but one can build a list by harvesting torrents, e.g. from big indexing sites and then extracting tracker lists from them.

To extract tracker URLs from a torrent file you a library that supports [bencoding](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#bencoding), a serialization format used in the bittorrent ecosystem.

Most torrents will either have a simple announce URL as described in [BEP-3](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#metainfo-files) or multiple as in [BEP-12](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0012.html)

Comment: that's i want to know,exactly. how do they extract the tracker list.how can i do it using perl or even python.it would be very interesting